# Install rbenv after ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I already have installed ruby 2.3.1p112 and rails 5.0.0 but I need install another version of ruby and rails, so I will install rbenv. What the right path to follow ? Do I need remove ruby and rails before install rbenv ?

Comment: I need install ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.2.5

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you're on OSX use homebrew and the configuration will probably take care of itself.

Comment: How did you already install Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5? Rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Have you tried the Rbenv install script?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I install Ruby with apt-get install ruby and gem install rails. But now I need early version of both. Ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.2.5

Comment: I don't use rvm nor rbenv.

Comment: I don't like using apt or yum; rbenv and RVM are much more usable for development. It's possible to tell rbenv to reuse previous installations of Ruby, but I wouldn't bother. Use [the rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to install it, then install the ruby-build plugin into rbenv, then install your Rubies and Rails. Once that's done then you can remove the previously install Ruby, which will remove that Rails along with it. Make sure you have the appropriate development tools and prerequisites installed first.

Answer (score 0):

as part of the installation you will add stuff to your bash profile which will clobber the system ruby / gem environment. You shouldn't have to do anything, just proceed with the rbenv install documentation.

Comment: Rbenv installed. but ruby -v still pointing to wrong ruby.

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`
`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`
`echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`
`exec $SHELL`

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`
`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`
`exec $SHELL`

`rbenv install 2.0.0-p648`
`Installed ruby-2.0.0-p648 to /home/ap/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p648`
`rbenv global 2.0.0-p648`
`ruby -v`
`ruby 2.3.1p112`

Comment: I run 
`apt-get purge ruby2.3`
`ruby -v 2.0.0p648`